# docker compose building and starting timeout

Tags: docker, docker-compose, timeout, httprequest, docker-build

I have been using my docker compose for a while, but today it's giving me this error for the first time, when I want to start or build my compose:

`An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.`
`If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).`

Why this is happening?
I found similar questions like mine, but their solutions won't work for me. I tried restarting my docker and even removing images and containers but I still get this error.
Also my docker compose doesn't include **tty** variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=300 docker-compose up -d
```

Please see [Compose CLI environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/) for full details.